# Serving geoIP targeted ads

Tags: geolocation, ip, maxmind, geotargetting

I am a publisher that is contracted to serve an ad to only US users. We are serving this ad using geoIP database from MaxMind to identify IP addresses.

Based on DoubleClick metrics, we are showing that of 3200 impressions served, 7% are still being served outside the US (Germany, France, India, Italy, UK with the most impressions).

Is there a better technology to geo-target ads to the US?

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercial geolocation technology provider. For free one, you can consider the http://lite.ip2location.com

Answer (score 0):

MaxMind precision service costs $0.0004 per lookup ... $20 gives you 50000 ip lookups. That is VERY cheap and much more accurate than goeiplite ..

GeoIP2 coun try costs $0.0001 so $20 gets you 200,000 lookups.

The only thing you need to block bots and spiders - or they will eat through your queries :D

Here: https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-services

I tried GeoIP2lite and it was horrible in tems of accurancy, but I needed CITY / ZIPCODE level - so I'm paying $10 / month for a much more accurate precision service

If you are serving ads, $20 is nothing for you